# Outer automorphism group and Nakayama automorphism.

Tags: representation-theory

[Herschend and Iyama](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3510.pdf), p.4.: For an arbitrary $n$-representation-finite algebra $\Lambda$, we denote by

$$\Pi:=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(\Lambda,\nu_n^{-i}\Lambda)$$

the corresponding $(n + 1)$-preprojective algebra, where $\mathcal{D}:=\mathcal{D}^b(\operatorname{mod} \Lambda)$ is the bounded derived category of the category $\operatorname{mod} \Lambda$ of all $\Lambda$-modules, $\nu_n:=\nu\circ[-n]$, and $\nu$ is the Nakayama functor:

$$\nu:=(D\Lambda)\otimes_{\Lambda}^{\mathbb{L}}- \simeq D\circ \mathbf{R}\operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}(-,\Lambda): \mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}$$

A **Nakayama automorphism** $\psi$ of $\Pi$ is an automorphism which gives an isomorphism $D\Pi \simeq \Pi_{\psi}$ of $\Pi \otimes \Pi^{\mathrm{op}}$-modules. **This is uniquely determined as an element of the outer automorphism group of $\Pi$.** ($\Pi_{\psi}$ is the $\Pi \otimes_{K} \Pi^{\text {op}}$-module such that the right action is given by $a \cdot b:=a \psi(b)$.)

---

**Question**: What is the outer automorphism group of $\Pi$? and why is Nakayama automorphism uniquely determined as an element of the outer automorphism group of $\Pi$? Thank you:)